# how to add nextjs favicon and work with docker compose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, next.js

i am adding favicon to my site in nextjs and testing localhost:3000 the favicon appears normally but when starting the site by docker it does not appear. This led me to imagine that I will have problems when deploying the site. How to adjust to work with docker container?

I created a favicon.ico file in `/public` and added it to the head

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Make sure the public assets get copied to the Docker image correctly. You can use this example Dockerfile as a reference: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?